# How do you execute ls -la when encoded as hex?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh, character-encoding

There used to be a really bad joke from the internet where you would copy something starting with \x0B\x2E... (just an example) and when you execute this command the terminal would interpret it as `sudo rm -rf /`.

How do you do this kind of obfuscation? I just tried running Cyberchef and turning my command, which is just `ls -la` into hex and this command doesn't execute even with `\x<hexcodetwocharactershere>\x<hexcodetwocharactershere>` syntax.

- What am I doing wrong?
- Are there any similar obfuscation methods?

P.S. I'm already aware of the base64 encoding trick, but that requires to have base64 installed on the system

To summarise, I would like to not use any other tools than bash to accomplish my goal (so no base64 encoding tools and similar, no xxd, no piping)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\x6c\x73\x20\x2d\x6c\x61` code, in most shells would try to run the `x6cx73x20x2dx6cx61` command as `\` is just another quoting operator.

In the `es` or `fish` shells, it would try to run the `ls -la` command and likely fail as there's no command by that name. In `es`, `\` is not a quoting operator but can be used to expand C-like escape sequences.

In fish `\` is both a quoting operator (like in `sh`/`csh`) and an escape sequence introducer like in `es`.

In both, `\x20` would not be interpreted as the token delimiter that a real space character is in the syntax of the shell, so it would not run the `ls` command with `-la` as argument.

Same if you entered `$'\x6c\x73\x20\x2d\x6c\x61'` in shells that support that ksh93-style form of quote.

You'd need the expansion of those to be interpreted as shell code, for instance by feeding it to `eval`, `sh -c`, `source`...

```
eval $'\x6c\x73\x20\x2d\x6c\x61'
```

Or at least for it to undergo splitting:

```
code=$'\x6c\x73\x20\x2d\x6c\x61'
$code # using split+glob in POSIX shells
$=code # explicit IFS-splitting in zsh
${(s[ ])code} # explicit splitting on space in zsh
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure this matches the spirit of the question, although it works with only bash:

```
eval "$(printf "%b" "\x6c\x73\x20\x2d\x6c\x61")"
```

You can check the decoded command before running it with

```
printf "%b\n" "\x6c\x73\x20\x2d\x6c\x61"
```

Comment: There used to be a way in Ubuntu (back in 2018/2019 at least) to execute shellcode/hexcode/smth similar. People used to say it's machine code, which I'm skeptical about. Can the terminal somehow execute machine code without a program to interpret it (besides bash itself)?

Comment: I’m not aware of a way to do that in a single step — you could write the shellcode to a file and then run that...

Comment: Though not standard `\xHH` is recognised in %b arguments by several implementations of `printf` including zsh's and GNU's, not only bash's builtin `printf`. See also ksh93's `eval $'\x6c...'` (to be included in the next POSIX version)